# Como atribuir permissões para usuários no OpenLDAP?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, openldap

Tenho um usuário(não é administrador) no OpenLDAP e quero dar permissão para alterar suas informações e senha, como posso fazer isso utilizando o phpLDAPadmin?

Comment: Para qualquer alteração no OpenLDAP (ou AD) o usuário precisa de permissão e, possívelmente no caso do AD, certificados. Somente consultas são liberadas

Comment: Você pode explicar quais os passos para fazer isso @gabriel-heming?